# ocultar div desde archivo php

Tags: php, hide

Tengo una función que llama a un archivo php, este archivo me devuelve un valor y en base a esto, en el success de ajax, oculto un div o no. 
Esto me supone un problema de seguridad y me preguntaba si desde el propio archivo de php al que llamo desde la función, yo podría ocultar el el div.

Comment: por que supone un problema de seguridad?

Comment: Según tengo entendido, se puede tener acceso al código Js y modificarlo. Ese div que yo oculto, se podría no ocultar. No esto muy seguro de lo que digo pero creo que es asi

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible. Desde el archivo `php` puedes ejecutar un `script` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

    $script = "<script> $(#idDelElemento).hide();</script>";
    echo $script;

?>
```

Dado que no das muchos datos esta es una solución un poco genérica, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: pero eso sigue siendo JS al final del camino

Comment: Si, pero te quitas de hacer una petición con javascript, como es ajax, que es donde podría haber más problemas. Aunque teniendo el php con las comprovaciones adecuadas no es necesario.

Comment: La llamada a php tengo que hacerla ya que necesito llamar a una api que me devuelve un valor.  No me ha funcionado el código de insertar js dentro de php.

Comment: La llamada a php mediante un formulario, la puedes hacer igual y te quitas de usar ajax. En cuanto a insertar js no te puedo decir más porque no sé que código tienes ni si usas un framework.